# Filter servlet not working with glassfish in netbeans

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, filter, glassfish

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

     <filter>
            <display-name>MyFilter</display-name>
            <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>AB_DB.MyFilter</filter-class>
          </filter>
          <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/MyFilter</url-pattern>
          </filter-mapping>
          <servlet>
            <description></description>
            <display-name>Profile</display-name>
            <servlet-name>Profile</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>AB_DB.Profile</servlet-class>
          </servlet>
          <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Profile</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/Profile</url-pattern>
          </servlet-mapping>
        </web-app>
```

This is the filter servlet I've tried

```
package AB_DB;


import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    public MyFilter() {
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String requri = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI().substring(((HttpServletRequest) request).getContextPath().length() + 1);
        System.out.println(requri);
        //if request uri starts with user/ then system will forward the request to Profile servlet
        if (requri.startsWith("user/")) {
            //get userid from request uri
            String id = requri.substring(5);
            System.out.println(id);

            //set attribute "user" with userid value
            request.setAttribute("user", id);

            //forward the request to Profile servlet
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/Profile")
                    .forward(request, response);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

}
```

However in the GlassFish 4 server log, there is no errors at all when running the project. The URI isnt even being printed out with 'System.out.println(id);' so I assume that the filter isnt even being injected.

Can anyone see any issues with my code? The sevlet Profile isn't being ran

Comment: what URL you are hitting  and expecting log on console ?

Comment: website.com/user/Surname1993

Comment: What `url-pattern` is your `Filter` and your `Servlet` mapped to?

Comment: infact im running on a local host so it would be localhost:8080/WebProject/user/Surname1993

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mapped oyur filter to `/MyFilter`

```
<url-pattern>/MyFilter</url-pattern>
```

and that doesn't match with URL you are requesting

```
/user/Surname1993
```

so your filter won't get invoked

Comment: So the url pattern would be /user/ ?

Comment: make it `/user/*` or even deeper based on your requirement